# php imap , get results only by senders email

Tags: php, email, imap

I am wanting to return emails of a specified senders email address only using IMAP and PHP, however the only example ive found that i can get working returns all emails, due to the amount of emails stored the code below takes a long time and often times out.

i have zero experience with this, and have read the php.net manual along with other resources so come to a dead end.

```
$mbox = imap_open("{outlook.office365.com:993/ssl}INBOX", "email-xxx", "pass-xxx")
     or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

$MC = imap_check($mbox);

// Fetch an overview for all messages in INBOX
$result = imap_fetch_overview($mbox,"1:{$MC->Nmsgs}",0);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: What is your question? Is this code not working as expected?

Comment: hi, sorry i have reworded my question to better explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[imap_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php)**.

```
array imap_search ( resource $imap_stream , string $criteria [, int $options = SE_FREE [, string $charset = NIL ]] )
```

To get only mails from foo@bar.baz:

```
$result = imap_search($mbox, 'FROM foo@bar.baz');
```

Comment: i've just given this ago, and it returns no results, i double checked my inbox and tried it on a couple of other emails that exist. but still nothing.